# Using R and SQL together in sf - what is an efficient workflow?

Tags: r, sql, sf

Do anyone have any tips/tricks/workflows for working with an SQL query within a `read_sf`/`st_read` function call in RStudio?

(I am struggling to figure out how to make a postgrsql/postgis example reproducible)

For example I have postgresql database I am querying with something like this:

```
  data = read_sf(conn, query = "SELECT h.col1, h.col2, h.geom
                      FROM table AS h
                      WHERE h.col1 = \'B\'")
```

First, I LOVE this because it returns an sf object and I get to stay in R but leverage the database. The problem is, I am finding it messy to contruct the query in RStudio as the query string doesn't format very nicely nor does the nested quotes thing work out very well here. So my question is what are people's workflows here? Obviously query can much more complicated than this and the formatting becomes very ugly. My junky solution right now is to open a SQL editor, write the query then paste it into `read_sf`.

tl;dr Combining R and SQL code into `read_sf` presents formatting challenges that make constructing queries inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Emacs then you can use one of the "multiple major mode" systems to do syntax highlighting for multiple languages within a single file. For example `polymode` - here's some screenshots that show R and C++ syntax highlighting in the same file:

https://polymode.github.io/screenshots/

I suspect R and SQL should be doable too. Submit a feature request to RStudio if you want this there.

[Emacs can work as a full R IDE, running R code from within itself, and editing scripts with highlighting, bracket-match flashing, spell checking and so on.]

Comment: Turns out there is an issue already @Spacedman: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2232. So you work in Emacs and employ polymode when including sql/postgis code as a string in `read_sf`?